# Word meaning "of or relating to songs"

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there any words that mean "of or relating to songs"?

I can think of [audio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/audio#Adjective), which means relating to any sound, or [melodic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/melodic), which is relating to just the melody within a song, but nothing about songs in general or musical compositions in general.

For example, I want to say

> This song is the ___ equivalent of Donald Trump - superficially attractive, but with no depth, and with disastrous consequences if it wins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply "musical"?

> "This song is the musical equivalent of Donald Trump ..."

Answer (score 0):

Has a Latin one though. Carmen is the Latin word for song. Its genitive singular is carminis. The genitive plural is carminum.

To answer your question, perhaps acoustic?